# String concatenation in the Helper in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to append the string in the helper function .

```
    content_tag(:span, :class => "a") do user.designation end +
    content_tag(:span, :class => "b") do user.number end
```

In the above, i am trying to append strings before the value user.designation and user.number.

```
like 
   do 
     "Designation : "+ user.designation end +
```

when i put like above i am getting error ..

How to resolve this ..

Answer (score 3):

Use the `concat` helper:

```
concat(content_tag(:span, :class => "a") { user.designation })
```